# Binding ISC DHCPD to a virtual (heartbeat) interface

Tags: networking, dhcp, isc-dhcp, virtual-ip

I had a DHCP server that acted as a relay endpoint and worked fine.

let's say this is a solo machine with eth0 with an ip of `192.168.0.10`

I needed to bring this server down and join it to a cluster, so, eth0 will be different, but, the ip `192.168.0.10` is now a cluster resource.

This works great and most services are working fine, but, isc-dhcpd doesn't appear to be virtual ip aware.

Requests are coming in on the correct `192.168.0.10` eth0:1 virtual interface, but, the response is going out via the standard eth0 interface which is causing endless DHCPREQUEST messages as the DHCP message is being discarded by the firewall or switch themselves.

I have tried various IPTABLES rules to spoof without much luck, and, I was just wondering if there is a correct way to bind ISC DHCPD to a virtual interface?

(FYI, tried the standard interfaces=eth0:1 without any luck :( )